# gnuplot - getting 24-bit grayscale

Tags: gnuplot

How can I make gnuplot plot in 16-bit (=65536 colors)? Setting the terminal e.g. to png with truecolor option it still yields 255 colors, as I have found out by importing it into ImageJ.

I have set the palette by:

`set palette defined ( 0 "black, 1 "white")`

The plot uses `pm3d map`

edit: I would need that functionality to take the generated plot, edit it with ImageJ and extract the original data. Since the data spans several orders of magnitude 255 grayshades are not sufficient to achieve reliable results by interpolating the corresponding grayvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot by itself doesn't support 16 bit grayscale images, because both libgd (used by the `png` terminal) and libcairo (used by the `pngcairo` terminal) support only 8 bits per channel (red, green, blue), which is actually truecolor.

I know, that the `postscript` terminal supports 12 bit for the `image` plotting style, which can be set with `set palette maxcolor 2**12`. Then you would need a program capable to convert this eps to a 16 bit png file. I don't know, if these 12 bits are available also with `pm3d`.

For what do need such a high resolution? Many other programs can't handle 16 bit pngs (e.g. gimp, which supports that only in the development version). And I'm sure, you cannot distinguish more than 128 gray tones ;)